# Send data to MySQL database using React Native and Laravel?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I have a website application built with Laravel, I want to create a registration form into the React Native mobile app and send that data to the MySQL database to store in their respective columns.

What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: I would start by learning what an API is and what its purpose is. After that, it should be straight forward what you need to do to implement the functionality you require i.e exposing endpoints responsible for updating your store that your mobile app is going to send requests to with some payload.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly open-ended question, but I'll provide a few basic pointers.

- First, you'll want to do client-side validation of registration form data, checking for things like required fields, password length, etc. There are many ways of doing that, here is one: https://medium.com/@pavsidhu/validating-forms-in-react-native-7adc625c49cf
- Your (validated) form data will make a `POST` request, with the form data as the `POST` body, to an API endpoint you will create in Laravel: https://blog.pusher.com/build-rest-api-laravel-api-resources/
- The endpoint will do any validation that can only be done server-side. This depends on your application, but for instance if you are building a user registration form, you will want to check to see if there is already a user by that email address.
- After validation, you'll want to save the data to the database with the laravel model you create for this form, if it doesn't already exist. The article above will show you how to do this.

Comment: I already have my API, I can fetch the data the thing I am figuring out is how to POST data to the database. I will take a look into those links, thank you!